# Unexpected error , Inappropriate Argument value ( or correct type)

Tags: python, jython, jes

Excuse my poor formatting this is my first post.
I'm simply trying to get my list as a float and to display accordingly. 
However I'm greeted with this error code.

> The error was: 1.91.6
>   Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
>   An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
>   Please check line 8 of F:\Inft1004\Assignment 1\NikGeorge_Assgt

heightData.txt contains the following:

2.1
1.9
1.6
2.3
2.2
1.6
1.8
1.9
2.1
1.8
1.6
1.5
2.2
1.8
1.7
1.8
1.9
  I have no idea what's causing it my code is as follows.

```
def calculateStatisticsFrom():  

 fileName = "heightData.txt"  
 fullPathName = getMediaPath(fileName)  
 print fullPathName  
 file = open(fullPathName, "r")  
 floats = []  
 for each in file:  
  floats.append(float(each.strip()))  

 printNow(floats)
```

Thanks for anyhelp. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: What is the content of `heightData.txt`?

Comment: 2.1
1.91.6
2.3
2.2
1.61.81.92.11.8
1.61.52.2
1.8
1.7
1.8
1.9

Comment: It might be clearer to post `heightData.txt` in the question then we can be clear about whether or not it contains carriage returns.

Comment: Sorry about that, meant to paste as you noted.
I haven't changed any code and the error has now changed. 
>The error was: 
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
Please check line 8 of F:\Inft1004\Assignment 1\NikGeorge_Assgt

Comment: I don't see any issue but I'm running on linux. `JES` seems to be masking the actual python exception message. Can you run it outside of `JES' and get the real error?

Comment: I can't sadly as I'm required to use JES, I have to have it done by tomorrow and this error has had be stumped all day.

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the error occurs?

Comment: `code`floats.append(float(each.strip()))

Comment: ok so you have 3 things on that line that might be causing the error. You could try breaking down each action to its own line and then see which causes the error. Also `print` the intermediate values looking for something wrong.

Comment: How would I go about that? 
I'm incredibly new to coding and essentially was told that I don't have to know how to use it at this time, just to use it. Which is great for them but horrible for me in this situation.

Comment: Replace `floats.append(float(each.strip()))` with `line=each.strip()` , `f=float(line)` and `floats.append(f)` each on a separate line. Then run that and find which one is bad.

Comment: The one that created the error is `code`f=float(line)

Comment: @PaulRooney
The one that created the error is codef=float(line)
The error message is:
The error was: 
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
Please check line 9 of F:\Inft1004\Assignment 1\NikGeorge_Assgt

Comment: Ok before that line add code "print line". See if the one it stops on looks wrong.

Comment: @PaulRooney It prints all the numbers from the file as to be expected however gives no indication of what could be wrong. atleast to me.

>>> calculateStatisticsFrom("heightData.txt")
2.1
1.9
1.6
2.3
2.2
1.6
1.8
1.9
2.1
1.8
1.6
1.5
2.2
1.8
1.7
1.8
1.9
F:\Inft1004\Assignment 1\heightData.txt
The error was: 
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
Please check line 9 of F:\Inft1004\Assignment 1\NikGeorge_Assgt

Comment: Check if you have any extra lines or strange characters at the end of your data file. Even better try recreating your data file. Cut and paste the numbers out of the question above and make sure that there is nothing before the first 2 and nothing after the last 9. Save it in notepad to ensure you don't get any exotic encodings.

Comment: That appears to of fixed the issue.  
It was even the file I downloaded from the course material, so kind of confusing how they'd miss something like that considering most in the course are beginners. 

Thank you for your help mate.

Comment: No probs. I made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has some context in the comments.

Try recreating your data file, from scratch. The original might have extra characters or have strange encodings. You could also try doing a diff (windiff) on the old and new data files to see what is different.

There's a chance your tutor had wanted you to deal with whatever it is that was causing the issue. If its a beginners course though this is not very likely. The file may have been mangled slightly in the HTTP download.

It seems like JES is catching exceptions that occurs and replacing the error message with a different one that's frankly not as useful (not to mention not familiar to other SO members) as the original python exception. To see the original python exception message you could temporarily wrap the offending line in a `try except` block and print out the exception message.

e.g.

```
try:
    floats.append(float(each.strip()))
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Comment: If I could upvote you I would, Thank you for all of your help. Honestly, you went so out of your way to help me with this.

Comment: No probs at all. Once we got started, had to see it through. Another thing worth mentioning is that in your code you don't close the file. You can call `file.close()` or use `with` to prevent the need to manually close the file manually.